# drop-down menu that lists columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a football website and I need someone to help me . I want to add a drop-down menu that lists columns of football competitions .Exactly in  "competitions " just like this [drop-down menu that lists columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcHUn.png).

@Mostafa Baezid Here is the code:

```html
<!-- outer-wrapper start -->
    
  <body>
 <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
<div class='navbar-header'>
  <button class='navbar-toggle' data-target='.js-navbar-collapse' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class='icon-bar'/>
    <span class='icon-bar'/>
    <span class='icon-bar'/>
  </button>
  <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>LOGO</a>
</div>


<div class='collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse'>
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>News</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>EUROPE</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>AFRICA</a></li> 
 <li><a href='#'>WORLDWIDE</a></li>
 
    <li class='dropdown mega-dropdown'>
      <a class='dropdown-toggle arrow' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Competitions <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down '/></a>

      <ul class='dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu'><!--megaMenu Wih 3 column start-->
        
        <li class='col-sm-4 nopadding'>
          <ul>
            <li class='dropdown-header'>France</li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
   <li class='divider'/>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='col-sm-4 nopadding'>
          <ul>
            <li class='dropdown-header'>Europe</li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li class='divider'/>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='col-sm-4 nopadding'>
          <ul>
            <li class='dropdown-header'>INTERNATIONAL</li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Demo Link</a></li>
            <li class='divider'/>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul><!--megaMenu Wih 3 column End-->

    </li>
 <li><a href='#'>Live Matches</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>Mercato</a></li> 
 <li><a href='#'>Videos</a></li> 
  </ul>
   
 </div>
<!-- /.nav-collapse -->
   </nav>


  <h1 class='c-text'> Mega Menu Demo  </h1>
<script type='text/javascript'>$(function () { $(&#39;.arrow&#39;).click(function () { $(&#39;.glyphicon-chevron-down&#39;).toggle(); }); }); </script>
</body>
        <div id='searchformfix'>
          <form action='/search' id='searchform'>
            <input name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;Text to Search...&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Text to Search...&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='Text to Search...'/>
          </form>
        </div>
      
     
      <div class='clear'/>


      <!-- secondary navigation menu end -->
      <!-- content wrapper start -->
```

Comment: Maybe you can use some ready components like bootstrap drop down menu: http://www.bootply.com/86684

Comment: Maybe if you don't want to use some ready components you can take a look here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp or stuff about dropdown (in your case nested) menu

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in bootstrap framework. [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/yr5bPNuuZ0). This is just an example. You can follow this. If you Have Any question ask me in comment. I will explain for you. Good Luck.
[N.B: Don't use !important on css if you have custom css file for your project. I use !important here because overwrite the css in same page.]

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  background: #f0f0f0;
  background: white;
}

nav.navbar-default{
  background: #35c353;
 }

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
   border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
color:white !important; 
font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
  color:black !important;
}
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;

}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  border-color:#35c353;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
    color: black !important;
    background-color:#35c353 !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #20ff4f;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 550px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #20ff4f;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 548px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999;
  white-space: normal;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background:#777;
}


h1.c-text{
text-align:center;}

/*Usefull class*/

.nopadding {
 padding-left:0 !important;
 padding-right:0 !important;
}
.nomargin{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

@media (max-width:947px) and (min-width:769px) {
 .navbar-nav {
display: inline-flex;
margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
 
  left: 495px !important;
 
 }

.mega-dropdown-menu:after {

  left: 495px !important;
 
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
 <!-- All links cdn's Before Body tag end  -->   
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
</div>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">EUROPE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AFRICA</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">WORLDWIDE</a></li>
 
    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle arrow" data-toggle="dropdown">Competitions <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down "></span></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu"><!--megaMenu Wih 3 column start-->
        
        <li class="col-sm-4 nopadding">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">France</li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-4 nopadding">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Europe</li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-4 nopadding">
          <ul>
            <li class="dropdown-header">INTERNATIONAL</li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Demo Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul><!--megaMenu Wih 3 column End-->

    </li>
 <li><a href="#">Live Matches</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Mercato</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li> 
  </ul>
   
 </div>
<!-- /.nav-collapse -->
   </nav><!-- /.nav-End -->

  <h1 class="c-text"> Mega Menu Demo  </h1>

  <!-- All Scripts Before Body tag end  -->     
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
  $('.arrow').click(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-chevron-down').toggle();
    });
 });  
</script>
</body>
```

Add this query this will display the navbar after click on the burger menu on mobile view(media screen 768)

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px)
{
.navbar-nav{

    display: block !important;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100% ;
    border: green !important;
    background: #35c353 !important;}

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply and for the effort u did to answer me   I appreciate that . that's what i was looking for , but there is a small problem the css style of menu bar must  be the same as on my website template (i mean the colors and the background of submenu list )  . I'm totally new to html and css. Im asking you if i can send to you the whole html and css codes and you do it for  me please

Comment: @A.king It's not a good Idea. Because if I complete your code You will never learn HTML CSS. I can help you if you have facing any problem with your code near future. But I can't do the  project for you. I gave you whole structure. Now it's your turn to learn something from here and use it. I'm really sorry.

Comment: First of all i wanna thank you for your efforts . Yes you're right it's not a good idea . I wish if i can do it my self. But i'm pissed off , I was trying from the morning until now  and nothing changed .  anyway  i just added the html code that u sent to me but i dunno where i'm going to add the css and javascript codes  here is how it looks when i added just the html code : https://football-seven.blogspot.com/ .

Comment: @A.king after login to you blogger.com you will see football-seven click on it. then select Template from left menu.. you will get 2 screen on live blog and mobile. below live on blog you will get edit HTML. Click on it. You will get all the html part. now add your code. For css beside edit html there is customize button. click on it select advance on right you will see Add CSS. Place your css there

Comment: Ok thank you another time , i'm gonna try . what about javascript ?

Comment: When place your html before body end tag add <script type="text/javascript">$(function () { $('.arrow').click(function () { $('.glyphicon-chevron-down').toggle(); }); }); 
</script>

Comment: Hii @Mostafa Baezid . I'm gonna put my code in answer and you check it please  because it doesn't work .

Comment: @A.king don't put your code in  answer .. edit it on your question

Comment: I don't know why you starting blogger for learning HTML CSS. but you don't place those html right way. and as I see you just copy the code and place it below your blog nav with another body tag. And those CDN's you don't add in your blog. So how they work [ http://megamenubootstrap.blogspot.com/ ] and one more thing. I think you need to go with basic first. I also Edit my Answer With basic.

Comment: hello @Mostafa , i thought that i'll not need to learn html and css  , but now i know that's very important . i edited my code but it still the same problem , please check my code here : view-source:https://football-seven.blogspot.com/  .N.B: i added the links in the line 7 and 8 of the code and the javascript code  in the line 2967 .

Comment: @A.king you already have a nav section line 2844-2876 replace with your nav section. And those script cdn's place those after line:3495. Or before line: 3574.

Comment: @A.king and one more thing. Right now there is a css which is .navbar{display:none;} in your index file that's why the navbar not display in your page.. So add this css .navbar{display:block !important;}.. if you want to see you navbar on current place you placed it.

Comment: I didn't find ' navbar{display:none;} ' in my index file and my index file is an html code i mean it's like this ' index.html ' and when i open it with my code editor , there is no css code,it shows just html code . please visit this link http://www.soratemplates.com/2015/06/sports-mag-blogger-templates.html and download then check the files please .

Comment: I see that before and it's xml content. But My Question is why you using this blogger. if you are learner . You can practice in localhost. Is this a project you are working ??

Comment: No it's not a project . I'm using this blogger just because i'm passionated about football and i wanna  take the experience of managing a football blog , that's it .

Comment: @A.king if you go t edit html on search /* FRAMEWORK */
navbar.post-feeds,.feed-links{display:none;} mabye you will find it on line 68.. remove the ' .navbar, '  from there.. Where do you want to place the navbar actually ?? On the top one or bottom one??

Comment: @A.king talk to you tomorrow. It's already 4.20AM .  [  euromagblog.blogspot.com  ] check the view source I place The nav inside a container div,  before the <!-- outer-wrapper start --> and end of the </header> tag And there is some issue In mobile view but rest are ok . Good luck

Comment: i wanna place it on the bottom one .

Comment: @A.king on mobile you need to change and write lots of css. Rest are ok. I hope you already seen my link. And  also see mu page source where I placed the navbar.

Comment: @A.king Solve the mobile view navbar also check my update on question. Add that to your media screen you will see the menu toggle on click. here is my demo blog link [ http://euromagblog.blogspot.com/ ]  good luck

Comment: i did what you said, the nav bar appear but there are some other problems you can check them here https://football-seven.blogspot.com/ . here is a link from where you can download my xml code ' http://hulkload.com/03k69o18kk0s ' and you edit it for me pleaaaaaase  (of course if you want  ) ,because i'm really pissed off . N.B: if you decided to do it for me , please delete the top nav bar i don't want it . And i'm so sorry for disturbing you with my questions these past few days .

Comment: @A.king Already download your zip file but I found a application. I don't find any xml file. And I don't think you follow my instruction because I already seen your source code. That's why I suggest you learn html and css first. And I don't feel disturb coz I love to code.  Anyways login to you blogger.com you will see football-seven click on it. then select Template from left menu.. you will get 2 screen on live blog and mobile. On top right corner on that page you will see a button "BackUp / Restore" Click that button. Popup window will appear click on download template. Send me that .xml

Comment: Yes you're right i have to learn html and css (please if yo have some good courses please share them with me ) .Here is the link you asked for http://hulkload.com/fh1t8hi8cdqf  , and please delete the top nav bar i don't want it .

Comment: i did all what you said . im using a macbook,  i think that's why it appears to you as an application  , sorry i can't use skype because im from Morocco and VOIP service is not available .  thanks , i visited this website maybe 3 or 4 days ago , i think it's very good . i'm gonna try to create txt file and send it to you or maybe we can use ' teamviewer ' .

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6tJg_ufiqc] see this video from 0.20 to 2.20 You will find how to save the .txt Waiting for it.

Comment: i can't do that because i'm using a macbook

Comment: just wait i'm gonna find a way

Comment: check this one  http://hulkload.com/n2oxzkb6nt56 if it doesn't work this one too , http://hulkload.com/dec16nb5q39s and let me know if it works .

Comment: @A.king sorry mate nothing on that doc.

Comment: @A.king got it. Will get update soon. It's 3AM here.

Comment: Okey as u want but please don't forget to delete top nav bar , Good night .

Comment: @A.king Sorry mate Your template is massed up coz its overflowing .. So now I'm working on the free sport mag theme.. Which is already you seen in my blog. I will update that xml like you want. And share that xml with you soon.

Comment: it's OK mate , take your time .

Comment: @A.king [ http://euromagblog.blogspot.com/  ] check out your demo navigation bar. that's all I can do for you.

Comment: that's good mate,  just change the green color to the orange like the style of of the template pleaase .

Comment: [ https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc5rnky8q7aj8z6/foot-ball%207.txt?dl=0 ] copy and past in your blog. [ euromagblog.blogspot.com ] demo looks. Now its your turn to create your own style . GOOD LUCK :)

Comment: Great job Mate thank you very much ,just one more thing ,wich part of the code where can i modify the color of menu bar  ?

Comment: if you open the txt file with any code editor from line 2112 to 2270. You will find the css for the custom navbar. Good luck

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help , i appreciate that mate .